# log4j and log4j-overslf4j both in classpath conflicts in LogManager

Tags: java, apache, maven, logging

we are using `log4j-over-slf4j` for logging in our application. But one of jar dependency in our application(External to us) needs log4j specific class(`org.apache.log4j.spi.RepositorySelector`). So, I have added log4j also in our classpath and It was able to find that class,
But, then I start to face new issue, In my code, I am loading RepositorySelectorfrom LogManager, 
`LogManager.setRepositorySelector(repoSel, guard);`
Now, instead of referring to log4j specific `LogManager`, It is referring to `log4j-over-slf4j` specific `LogManager`, due to which , I am getting below error in websphere server console.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager.setRepositorySelector(Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/RepositorySelector;Ljava/lang/Object;)V**

Please help me know, how can we remove the conflict, so that, It's able to refer proper log4j1.2.15 specific `LogManager`.
And, as jar which is using log4j is external to our system, we don't have much control over that.

Below is the complete stack trace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager.setRepositorySelector(Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/RepositorySelector;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.hsbc.es.logging.def.impl.log4j.Log4jLoggingTypeProvider.setContextualRepositorySelector(Log4jLoggingTypeProvider.java:117)
    at com.hsbc.es.logging.def.impl.log4j.Log4jLoggingTypeProvider.<clinit>(Log4jLoggingTypeProvider.java:97)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1887)
    at com.hsbc.es.logging.LoggingTypeManagerFactory.discoverContextLoggingTypeManagerSPI(LoggingTypeManagerFactory.java:168)
    at com.hsbc.es.logging.LoggingTypeManagerFactory.getContextLoggingTypeManagerSPI(LoggingTypeManagerFactory.java:98)
    at com.hsbc.es.logging.def.LoggingTypeProviderFactory.getContextLoggingTypeProvider(LoggingTypeProviderFactory.java:49)
    at com.hsbc.es.logging.def.LoggingTypeFactory.getDebugger(LoggingTypeFactory.java:58)
```

Comment: Remove `log4j.jar`. If you can't fix the jar to not rely on Log4j SPI, you may have to manually write a stub/proxy, so it'll run without Log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the transitive log4j dependency from being imported by the dependency that includes it.

In your pom.xml you can tell update your dependency import in order to exclude log4j:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>the.group.id</groupId>
    <actifactId>the.artifact.id</artifactId>
    <version>version-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```